# Razor ASP.NET button onclick event inside @RenderPage() not working

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, button, razor, onclick

I have a form inside a modal which is working fine with submit and clear buttons on the modal..

The form is rendered inside the modal using @RenderPage() method from ASP.NET.

I wanted to add a button inside the form and on click I wanted to that button print me Hello on the console, but nothing is happening.

Here is some code:

This is my modal code inside Index.cshtml file:

```
<div id="addItemViewModal" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title">Add Report Catalogue</h4>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">X</button>
            </div>
            @RenderPage("FormBody.cshtml");
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" form="reportCatalogueForm">Save</button>
                <button id="btnClearFormAddItem" type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Clear</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<button id="btnShowAddItemModal" class="btn btn-secondary" type="button">Add Report Catalog</button>
```

this is part of my form code inside FormBody.cshtml file with the button and the script in the end:

```
<form id="reportCatalogueForm" method="post">
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

    <div id="formPage1">
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ReportCatalogue.Id)
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ReportCatalogue.ComponentName,
            htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-6" })
            <div class="col-md-8">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ReportCatalogue.ComponentName,
                new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ReportCatalogue.ComponentName,
                "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ReportCatalogue.ComponentDescription,
            htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-6" })
            <div class="col-md-12">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ReportCatalogue.ComponentDescription,
                new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ReportCatalogue.ComponentDescription,
                "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ReportCatalogue.OwnerName,
            htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-6" })
            <div class="col-md-8">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ReportCatalogue.OwnerName,
                new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ReportCatalogue.OwnerName,
                "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ReportCatalogue.OwnerEmail,
            htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-6" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ReportCatalogue.OwnerEmail,
                new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ReportCatalogue.OwnerEmail,
                "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ReportCatalogue.OwnerRole,
            htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-6" })
            <div class="col-md-6">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ReportCatalogue.OwnerRole,
                new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ReportCatalogue.OwnerRole,
                "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>            
        <br />            
        <button class="btn btn-secondary formButton" type="button" onclick="test()">Next</button>
    </div>
    .
    .
    .
    <script>
        function test(){
             console.log('Hello');
        };
    </script>
```

For some reason the function is never called, don't know if it as to do because of this page is being rendered with Razor @RenderPage() or if it is something I'm missing here??

Can anyone help me on these?

Best Regards

Comment: the script tag isn't closed in `FormBody.cshtml`

Comment: @GhanshyamSingh thank you for catching that, bu it was my mistake when passing the code to stackoverflow, i edited the question and closed the script tag.